# How to provide a dynamic DataSource as a const in a Service?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have a constant where I save a hard coded JSON Object and I use it as DataSource in my service to create a data table with pagination etc.

```
const registeredUser:USers[] = [
  {_id: "11", email: "jane.doe@foo.de", fullName: "Jane Doe", created: "2017-06-14T16:06:44.457Z"},
  {_id: "59", email: "john.doe@foo.de", fullName: "John Doe", created: "2017-06-16T10:50:51.180Z"},
  ....
];

@Injectable()
export class ListUserService {
    constructor(public loginService:LoginService){}
    getUserDatasource(page:number, limit:number, sortBy?:string, sortType?:DatatableSortType): IPaginableUsers {
        const offset = (page - 1) * limit;
        let users;
        if (sortBy) {
            // HERE WHERE I USE/NEED the registeredUser DataSource
            users = registeredUser.sort((user1:USers, user2:USers) => {
        }
        ....
   ....
}
```

So the issue is that I would like to get rid of the hard coded DataSource and get the date dynamically from other Service where it works fine.

Therefore I have created a function in this Service: **`ListUserService`**. which catches the data from the other Service **`LoginService`** and passing it to: **`const registeredUser:USers[]`**. 
`USers[]` is an interface.

Code:

```
const registeredUser:USers[] = this.getData ();

@Injectable()
export class ListUserService {
    constructor(public loginService:LoginService){}
    getUserDatasource(page:number, limit:number, sortBy?:string, sortType?:DatatableSortType): IPaginableUsers {
        const offset = (page - 1) * limit;
        let users;
        if (sortBy) {

        } 
    }

    getData () {
        this.loginService.getUsersList().subscribe(
            (res) => {
               console.log(JSON.stringify(res.message));
               return res.message;
            }, (err) => {

            }
        )
    }
}
```

Unfortunately **`ng build -prod`** runs fine without errors. But the Chrome console throws following error: **`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.getData is not a function`**

In a way I understand the error as I'am trying to invoke the function `getData()` out of the class and before the Service is interpreted.

So, How can I make the returned JSON Object from `getData()` available as DataSource to: **`registeredUser:USers[]`**.

Should I create a second class in **`ListUserService`** and get an instance of it in order to be passed to **`registeredUser:USers[]`**. Would this help?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need `registeredUser:USers[]` to be available outside the `ListUserService` class?

Assuming your login service looks something like this:

```js
export class LoginService {
    getUsersList(): Promise<Users[]> {
        // ... //
    }
}
```

you could just use it inside the method like so...

```js
@autoinject
export class ListUserService {
    constructor(private loginService: LoginService) { }

    async getUserDatasource(page: number, limit: number, sortBy?: string, sortType?: DatatableSortType): Promise<IPaginableUsers> {

        const users = await this.loginService.getUsersList();

        const offset = (page - 1) * limit;

        if (sortBy) {
            // ... //
        } 
    }
}
```

And if you didn't want to fetch it from the server with every call to `LoginService.getUsersList`, you could implement some kind of caching inside the LoginService or ListUserService.

Failing that, you could move the `registeredUser` property inside your `ListUserService`. Not tested, but something like...

```js
@Injectable()
export class ListUserService {
    constructor(public loginService:LoginService){}

    getUserDatasource(page:number, limit:number, sortBy?:string, sortType?:DatatableSortType): IPaginableUsers {
        const offset = (page - 1) * limit;
        let users;
        if (sortBy) {

        } 
    }

    private registeredUser:USers[];

    getData () {
        this.loginService.getUsersList().subscribe(
            (res) => {
               console.log(JSON.stringify(res.message));
               this.registeredUser = res.message; // may need to process or map the data into your USers type?
            }, (err) => {

            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: No, the `login.servcie.ts` contains a couple if method which are called and used in different components: `@Injectable()
export class LoginService{..... method1(){}; method2(){}; method3(){}..}`.
I tried the second suggestion, but it seems like the `registeredUser ` remains empty. Error: `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined`

Comment: By the way, `registeredUser:USers[]` must not be outside of `ListUserService` class.